# Is there a hotkey to toggle between the two panes only in Nautilus (with Extra Pane/F3 mode)?

Tags: 10.04, nautilus

I am running Nautilus with the Extra Pane feature enabled. But I am missing a keyboard shortcut to switch between the left and right pane. Is there a shortcut key for toggling just between the left and right file pane? Something that works like tab in Total Commander/Midnight Commander?

Tab and Shift-Tab are not what I'm looking for. They cycle through several other GUI elements in addition to the two panes.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 if that matters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<kbd>F6</kbd> switches between the two panes. You don't need to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This works on 10.04.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Status Bar the control will be to the first element on it. But if you remove the status bar by choosing "Status Bar" in the view menu, the control will move to the right side file browser's column when pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> will take the control to the left side file browser's column when in the right side.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make it a bit easier to move the focus from the left to the right pane and back is to disable the `Location Bar` from `View`.

With the `Location Bar` disabled you can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to move the focus to the right and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to move it to the left.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

<kbd>F6</kbd> may not work on many systems. (like mine has <kbd>F6</kbd> assigned to the mute volume option by default). Use <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> in that case.

**Method 2:**

Also here's what I do to effectively switch between the two without having to

> cycle through several other GUI elements in addition to the two panes.

1. When in the Extra pane, press <kbd>→</kbd> to switch focus to the default pane
2. When in the Default pane, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch focus back to the extra pane