# In a "Save as ... " dialog, what's the quickest way to keyboard-navigate to "Recently Used" in the "Places" side-pane of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, navigation

With [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28234/is-there-a-hotkey-to-toggle-between-the-two-panes-only-in-nautilus-with-extra-) and [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/709098) in mind, what's the quickest way to **keyboard**-navigate to "**Recently Used**" in the "**Places**" side-pane in a (*Nautilus*) "**Save as ...** " dialog?

Currently, the quickest ( ! ) way I know of is to <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> a number of times, possibly taking a shortcut along the way by hitting <kbd>F6</kbd>, which will save three of the *many* <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>'s.

Clearly, this is *neither* quick *nor* efficient. Any ideas?

Comment: for navigating to bookmarks etc there's a different solution here http://askubuntu.com/questions/284707/in-a-save-as-dialog-whats-the-quickest-way-to-keyboard-navigate-to-tmp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my English Ubuntu 12.10, when I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the "P" in "Places" becomes underlined. This gives the hint that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will move focus to the "Places" bar.

The accelerator might be different in another release or a localized version of Ubuntu. Also note that some characters in other labels become underlined, too -- the logic is the same here.

This works in many other dialogs in Ubuntu and Windows.

**EDIT**: Beyond that logic, hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> selects "Recently used" in the "Places" bar *and* leaves the focus in the "Files" pane.

**EDIT 2:** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> selects "Desktop".

Comment: Brilliant! Hadn't crossed my mind to think of an accelerator for this... I'll leave the question open for a bit still, but this is likely to be the accepted answer!

Comment: Hmm, it's still not as smooth as I'd hope: when I use **`Alt P`**, I immediately land in "**Search**"; how do I get from "Search" to "**Recently Used**"? The down arrow activates the search field, rather than focussing "Recently Used". So close, but still far away...?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: Not on my system. Which application are you testing? On what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm on precise. Which application? Well, just take Firefox as an example: if I want to save the very page I'm writing this on, get to `Save as ...` dialog, hit `Alt P` to focus **Places** in side-bar. Within Places, `tmp` (currently) is selected, presumably because earlier today I downloaded a (pdf) file to `tmp`. But before downloading to `tmp`, "**Search**" was selected (don't know why; I rarely use that "Search" in Places). But even now that `tmp` is selected: how do I (quickly & efficiently) get to "**Recently Used**"? From `tmp` I'm bound to traverse (Bookmarks and) unmounted partitions.

Comment: Another example: wanting to print-to-pdf (`Print to File`) from Firefox, click on `Save in Folder`, `Other...`, `Alt P` - and again land in "**Search**".

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: Try `Alt R`, see also my edit.

Comment: doh! I feel quite stupid now... thx for bearing with me!!

Comment: I'm still trying to find the accelerator (and/or quickest way) to select (focus) the `tmp` folder and my bookmarks, *without* having to traverse and mount other filesystems (which are in between `Recently Used`, `Home folder`, `Desktop` and `tmp`, bookmarks). Any idea how?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty: Hit <kbd>T</kbd> once you are in the "Places" pane? Otherwise, I have no idea...

Comment: Nope, doesn't work AFAICT. Maybe I ought to start a new question for this. But Regarding your original answer: tons of thanks, helps me a lot!

Comment: found a solution, posted it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/284707/in-a-save-as-dialog-whats-the-quickest-way-to-keyboard-navigate-to-tmp