# In a “Save as … ” dialog, what's the quickest way to keyboard-navigate to “tmp” and to indiv. bookmarks in the “Places” side-pane of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, bookmarks, tmp, navigation

Building on my [earlier question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/269637/in-a-save-as-dialog-whats-the-quickest-way-to-keyboard-navigate-to-rec), where the accepted answer used keyboard accelerators for some elements of the dialog,

- I'm still trying to find the accelerator (and/or quickest way) to select (focus) the

  - `tmp` folder and
  - my `bookmarks`
    in the “`Places`” side-pane of `Nautilus`' “Save as … ” dialog,
- ***without*** having to <strike>traverse and mount other filesystems</strike>, which are *in between*

  - `Recently Used`, `Home`, `Desktop`
    --- *and* ---
  - `tmp`, `bookmarks`.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 2):

this may still be optimized further, but just serendipitously discovered *this* which goes most (or even all) of the way:

- if you start in the `Name` field, just use the <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> cursor key once, twice or thrice (even *that* will sometimes get you to the `bookmarks` in the `places` pane)
- alternatively and additionally (which is my *new* discovery), you may (also) find using the <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> (note that <kbd>F6</kbd> does sth similar) useful in switching from the directory-content-pane directly to  `Bookmarks` in the `Places` pane.

---

**Edit**

- to skip mounting the drives "in between", using <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> in `Places` does seem to work... it still feels a bit clumsy (requiring <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> occasionally) though...

Comment: this is not "the final thing" yet; sometimes I still can't find a way to skip mounting the drives.......